# Duplicate object multiple times based on array length - Angular 2+/ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, ionic-framework

I have an object with empty values. I need to duplicate this object however many times the length of one of my arrays is. So then I would have two objects with the same properties but with different values.

TS

```
add = [
    {
      type: 'Package',
      value: ''
    }
]

this.form.value.packages = [1,2,3]

//This should duplicate the object based on length of packages

let packageDup = Array(this.form.value.packages.length).fill(this.add[0])

packageDup.forEach((res, i) => {

     packageDup[i].value = this.form.value.packages[i]

})
```

The issue with this method is that the values end up being the same. For instance, both object's value would be equal to 2. I feel like I'm overthinking this one. Thanks.

What I would like as a result ---

```
add = [
        {
          type: 'Package',
          value: '1'
        },
        {
          type: 'Package',
          value: '2'
        }, 
        {
          type: 'Package',
          value: '3'
        }
    ]
```

Comment: either that i'm so sleepy or your code and explanation are confusing

Comment: Ok I'll try to edit it and make it more understandable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a copy of the object 'obj', I usually use `Object.assign({}, obj)`

you could use something like this :

```
let packageDup = Array(this.form.value.packages.length)
    .fill(0) // needed to have some value and no empty value that would cause map to fail.
    .map(x => Object.assign({}, this.add[0]);
```

(as Daniel W Strimpel mentionned in his answer, be aware that it performs only a shallow copy, in case you have nested objects you should keep that in mind.)

```js
let baseObject = { value: 1 }

let array = Array(3).fill(0).map(x => Object.assign({}, baseObject));

console.log(array);

array[1].value = 2;
array[2].value = 3;

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately, getting this as a result - [empty × 2], empty array. It needs to two empty value objects -> this.add[0]

Comment: yes exactly, I have to fill the array with something first. I'll edit my answer, but I also added an working executable simpler example

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to create an array of a certain size and fill it using syntax like this:

```
Array(this.form.value.packages.length).fill(this.add[0])
```

You can just use the `map` operator on your `this.form.value.packages` array to skip all of that work:

```
add = [
  {
    type: 'Package',
    value: ''
  }
]

this.form.value.packages = [1,2]

let packages = this.form.value.packages.map(v => {
    return Object.assign({}, this.add[0], { value: v });
});
```

As a general note, `Object.assign(...)` does a shallow copy which is fine for the example object you had, but if you have a more complex object with properties that are nested objects this won't work. In that case, you would need to use a library like underscore to do a deep clone of your `this.add[0]` object.

As @Eliseo pointed out in the comment below, if you do indeed have an object as simple as you have shown, you can simply do:

```
let packages = this.form.value.packages.map(v => ({ type: 'Package', value: v }));
```

Comment: if the object is so simple, you needn't use Object.assign, just packages=thisform.value.packages.map(v=>{type:'Package',value:v})

Comment: @Eliseo yup. I'm just assuming that the object is more complex and is why the OP was doing all of that work in the first place.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Wish I could give the answer to both of you guys, however, the guy below was first. Appreciate it!

Comment: and have an upvote for mentionning the fact that Object.assign does a shallow copy, one should always keep that in mind.